# POST request not working

Tags: ethernet, datalogging

I'm following a guide on storing sensor data to MySQL:

[Guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/PART-1-Send-Arduino-data-to-the-Web-PHP-MySQL-D3js/#step1)

My POST request isn't getting any results to my server. For now, I'm only storing temperature.

Here is my code for saving data:

```cpp
void sendData(double input) {
  String data = "sensorid=3000000&temp=" + doubleToString(input, 2) + "&hum=1.2";
  
  if (client.connect("192.168.1.50", 80)) {
    client.println("POST /arduino/add.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.1.50");
    // client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
    // client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print(data.length());
    client.println();
    client.print(data);

    Serial.println("Sent data: " + data);
  }
  
  if (client.connected()) {
    client.stop(); 
  }

  delay(300000);
}
```

I've commented out two headers since it did not give any other results. My `Serial.println` gives: Sent data: sensorid=3000000&temp=24.00&hum=1.2, which means that the Arduino is connected to the given IP-adress and that my request data is as I want. They are also working perfectly when I'm testing with [Requestmaker](http://requestmaker.com/), so I'm pretty sure my error comes from the way I'm doing the request here.

Do you have any idea how I can solve or debug this?

Comment: There needs to be an empty line between the headers and the body of the request. Therefore you have to `println()` (not `print()`) the end of the last header.

Comment: Try to use print() with '\n' at the end (only a newline, not carriage return.

`xportSendTextNoLine("C192.168.200.136/80\n");
sprintf(request,"GET /debug.php?dat=%u HTTP/1.0\n\n",value);
xportSendTextNoLine(request);` <-- This worked for me. But you'll have to change it a bit to arduino code.

Comment: did you solve this problem. I am having exactly the same issue and came to the same conclusion: the error comes from the way I am doing the request from the arduino.

Comment: yes, the first comment was the solution to my problem. End with println instead of print. Could not mark it as answer since it was only a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answered by Edgar Bonet*

There needs to be an empty line between the headers and the body of the request. Therefore you have to `println()` (not `print()`) the end of the last header.